# Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (null). Spring Social facebook login

Tags: java, spring, facebook, facebook-login, spring-social

I have some problems with facebook login integration.
Here is my Social configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConfig.class);

    @Inject
    Environment environment;

    @Inject
    ConnectionRepository customSocialConnectionRepository;

    @Inject
    SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, customSocialConnectionRepository);
        controller.addInterceptor(new FacebookCustomConnectInterceptor());
        return controller;
    }

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        // Facebook configuration
        String facebookClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientId");
        String facebookClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientSecret");
        if (facebookClientId != null && facebookClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuration FacebookConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                    new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                            facebookClientId,
                            facebookClientSecret
                    )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure FacebookConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new CustomSocialUsersConnectionRepository(socialUserConnectionRepository, connectionFactoryLocator);
    }
}
```

I have domain object for store SocialUserConnection.

I override ConnectionRepository

```
public class CustomSocialConnectionRepository implements ConnectionRepository {

    private String userId;

    private SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;

    private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator;

    public CustomSocialConnectionRepository(String userId, SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository, ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.socialUserConnectionRepository = socialUserConnectionRepository;
        this.connectionFactoryLocator = connectionFactoryLocator;
    }

    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, Connection<?>> findAllConnections() {
        List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections = socialUserConnectionRepository.findAllByUserIdOrderByProviderIdAscRankAsc(userId);
        List<Connection<?>> connections = socialUserConnectionsToConnections(socialUserConnections);
        MultiValueMap<String, Connection<?>> connectionsByProviderId = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        Set<String> registeredProviderIds = connectionFactoryLocator.registeredProviderIds();
        for (String registeredProviderId : registeredProviderIds) {
            connectionsByProviderId.put(registeredProviderId, Collections.emptyList());
        }
        for (Connection<?> connection : connections) {
            String providerId = connection.getKey().getProviderId();
            if (connectionsByProviderId.get(providerId).size() == 0) {
                connectionsByProviderId.put(providerId, new LinkedList<>());
            }
            connectionsByProviderId.add(providerId, connection);
        }
        return connectionsByProviderId;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Connection<?>> findConnections(String providerId) {
        List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections = socialUserConnectionRepository.findAllByUserIdAndProviderIdOrderByRankAsc(userId, providerId);
        return socialUserConnectionsToConnections(socialUserConnections);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <A> List<Connection<A>> findConnections(Class<A> apiType) {
        List<?> connections = findConnections(getProviderId(apiType));
        return (List<Connection<A>>) connections;
    }

    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, Connection<?>> findConnectionsToUsers(MultiValueMap<String, String> providerUserIdsByProviderId) {
        if (providerUserIdsByProviderId == null || providerUserIdsByProviderId.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to execute find: no providerUsers provided");
        }

        MultiValueMap<String, Connection<?>> connectionsForUsers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : providerUserIdsByProviderId.entrySet()) {
            String providerId = entry.getKey();
            List<String> providerUserIds = entry.getValue();
            List<Connection<?>> connections = providerUserIdsToConnections(providerId, providerUserIds);
            connections.forEach(connection -> connectionsForUsers.add(providerId, connection));
        }
        return connectionsForUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection<?> getConnection(ConnectionKey connectionKey) {
        SocialUserConnection socialUserConnection = socialUserConnectionRepository.findOneByUserIdAndProviderIdAndProviderUserId(userId, connectionKey.getProviderId(), connectionKey.getProviderUserId());
        return Optional.ofNullable(socialUserConnection)
            .map(this::socialUserConnectionToConnection)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchConnectionException(connectionKey));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <A> Connection<A> getConnection(Class<A> apiType, String providerUserId) {
        String providerId = getProviderId(apiType);
        return (Connection<A>) getConnection(new ConnectionKey(providerId, providerUserId));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <A> Connection<A> getPrimaryConnection(Class<A> apiType) {
        String providerId = getProviderId(apiType);
        Connection<A> connection = (Connection<A>) findPrimaryConnection(providerId);
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new NotConnectedException(providerId);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <A> Connection<A> findPrimaryConnection(Class<A> apiType) {
        String providerId = getProviderId(apiType);
        return (Connection<A>) findPrimaryConnection(providerId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addConnection(Connection<?> connection) {
        Long rank = getNewMaxRank(connection.getKey().getProviderId()).longValue();
        SocialUserConnection socialUserConnectionToSave = connectionToUserSocialConnection(connection, rank);
        socialUserConnectionRepository.save(socialUserConnectionToSave);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateConnection(Connection<?> connection) {
        SocialUserConnection socialUserConnection = socialUserConnectionRepository.findOneByUserIdAndProviderIdAndProviderUserId(userId, connection.getKey().getProviderId(), connection.getKey().getProviderUserId());
        if (socialUserConnection != null) {
            SocialUserConnection socialUserConnectionToUdpate =  connectionToUserSocialConnection(connection, socialUserConnection.getRank());
            socialUserConnectionToUdpate.setId(socialUserConnection.getId());
            socialUserConnectionRepository.save(socialUserConnectionToUdpate);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeConnections(String providerId) {
        socialUserConnectionRepository.deleteByUserIdAndProviderId(userId, providerId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeConnection(ConnectionKey connectionKey) {
        socialUserConnectionRepository.deleteByUserIdAndProviderIdAndProviderUserId(userId, connectionKey.getProviderId(), connectionKey.getProviderUserId());
    }

    private Double getNewMaxRank(String providerId) {
        List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections = socialUserConnectionRepository.findAllByUserIdAndProviderIdOrderByRankAsc(userId, providerId);
        return socialUserConnections.stream()
            .mapToDouble(SocialUserConnection::getRank)
            .max()
            .orElse(0D) + 1D;
    }

    private Connection<?> findPrimaryConnection(String providerId) {
        List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections = socialUserConnectionRepository.findAllByUserIdAndProviderIdOrderByRankAsc(userId, providerId);
        if (socialUserConnections.size() > 0) {
            return socialUserConnectionToConnection(socialUserConnections.get(0));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private SocialUserConnection connectionToUserSocialConnection(Connection<?> connection, Long rank) {
        ConnectionData connectionData = connection.createData();
        return new SocialUserConnection(
            userId,
            connection.fetchUserProfile().getEmail(),
            connection.getKey().getProviderId(),
            connection.getKey().getProviderUserId(),
            rank,
            connection.getDisplayName(),
            connection.getProfileUrl(),
            connection.getImageUrl(),
            connectionData.getAccessToken(),
            connectionData.getSecret(),
            connectionData.getRefreshToken(),
            connectionData.getExpireTime()
        );
    }

    private List<Connection<?>> providerUserIdsToConnections(String providerId, List<String> providerUserIds) {
        List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections = socialUserConnectionRepository.findAllByUserIdAndProviderIdAndProviderUserIdIn(userId, providerId, providerUserIds);
        return socialUserConnectionsToConnections(socialUserConnections);
    }

    private List<Connection<?>> socialUserConnectionsToConnections(List<SocialUserConnection> socialUserConnections) {
        return socialUserConnections.stream()
            .map(this::socialUserConnectionToConnection)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Connection<?> socialUserConnectionToConnection(SocialUserConnection socialUserConnection) {
        ConnectionData connectionData = new ConnectionData(socialUserConnection.getProviderId(),
            socialUserConnection.getProviderUserId(),
            socialUserConnection.getDisplayName(),
            socialUserConnection.getProfileURL(),
            socialUserConnection.getImageURL(),
            socialUserConnection.getAccessToken(),
            socialUserConnection.getSecret(),
            socialUserConnection.getRefreshToken(),
            socialUserConnection.getExpireTime());
        ConnectionFactory<?> connectionFactory = connectionFactoryLocator.getConnectionFactory(connectionData.getProviderId());
        return connectionFactory.createConnection(connectionData);
    }

    private <A> String getProviderId(Class<A> apiType) {
        return connectionFactoryLocator.getConnectionFactory(apiType).getProviderId();
    }
}
```

and UsersConnectionRepository (http://pastebin.com/7UzsndJq)

I use ConnectController to handle facebook connection, register and login user into application.

```
public class FacebookCustomConnectInterceptor implements ConnectInterceptor<Facebook> {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FacebookCustomConnectInterceptor.class);

    @Inject
    SocialService socialService;

    @Inject
    CustomSocialUsersConnectionRepository customSocialUsersConnectionRepository;

    @Inject
    SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;

    @Override
    public void preConnect(ConnectionFactory<Facebook> connectionFactory, MultiValueMap<String, String> valueMap, WebRequest request) {
        // events before connection
    }
    @Override
    public void postConnect(Connection<Facebook> connection, WebRequest request) {
        UserProfile userProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();


        socialService.loginOrCreateFacebookUser(userProfile);

    }
}

public void loginOrCreateFacebookUser(UserProfile userProfile) {

        SocialUserConnection socialUserConnection = socialUserConnectionRepository.findOneByEmailAndProviderId(userProfile.getEmail(), "facebook");

        Optional<User> foundUser = userRepository.findByUsername(socialUserConnection.getEmail());

        User user = new User();
        if(!foundUser.isPresent()) {
            user.setUsername(socialUserConnection.getEmail());
            user.setEmail(socialUserConnection.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(RandomUtil.generatePassword());
            user.setActivated(true);
            Authority authority = authorityRepository.findOne("ROLE_USER");
            Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            authorities.add(authority);
            user.setAuthorities(authorities);

            user = userRepository.save(user);
        }
        else {
            user = foundUser.get();
        }

        String lowercaseLogin = user.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin,
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
```

The problem is when i try to run some functions in postConnect. When i try to do this i got error:
WARN 3232 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.connect.web.ConnectController      : Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (null). Redirecting to facebook connection status page.

Full stack:
http://pastebin.com/QXGtv3xe

I can't post more than 2 links :)

I use Spring Boot 1.3.5

Comment: My facebook app oauth2 config:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/6zAxh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook/issues/25

```
Create a your own User Class with the fields you required.
(Fields that are able to use:
{ "id", "about", "age_range", "birthday", "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education", "email", "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people", "installed", "install_type", "is_verified", "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", "name", "name_format", "political", "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status", "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other", "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id", "updated_time", "verified", "video_upload_limits", "viewer_can_send_gift", "website", "work"})

Replace the code similar to follow:
String [] fields = { "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name" }; //Depends on which field you want.
User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```